# filter json array based on multiple arguments including lists

Tags: javascript, json

So I am trying to filter a json array with these two lists. what I want is if any of the element from these lists are in json array I want them in the output.
this is my json array.

```
[{
        "sector_code": "0828", "listed_in": ["ALLSHR,KMIALLSHR" ],
    },
    {
        "sector_code": "0828","listed_in": [ "KMI30"],
    },
    {
        
        "sector_code": "0824","listed_in": ["KSE100,ALLSHR,KMIALLSHR"],
    },
    {
        "sector_code": "0833","listed_in": [ "KSE100", 'KMIALLSHR', 'LST30'],
    }]
```

And I have two arrays one is

```
listed_inilter = ['KSE100', 'KMIALLSHR']
sector_code = ['0833', '0824']
```

What I want is output the data from the json array even if any of the value from each list is matching.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, could you share your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on. Study about method [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in javascript to know what the code below does.

```js
  const array = [{ sector_code: ..., listed_in: ... }]; // your array
  const listed_inilter = ['KSE100', 'KMIALLSHR'];
  const sector_code = ['0833', '0824'];

  function array_subset() {
     return array.filter(element => {
       const is_listed = listed_inilter.some(item => element.listed_in.includes(item));

       const is_sector = sector_code.includes(element.sector_code);

       return (is_listed || is_sector)
  });
}

console.log(array_subset()); // output the filtered list
```